# Change http headers inside an angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I need to change http headers from inside a controller. It works in config by using $httpProvider but thats not what I am looking for.

I tried this but it says push of undefined.

```
$http.interceptors.push([function() {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            //add nonce to avoid CSRF issues
            config.headers['X-WP-Nonce'] = myLocalized.nonce;

            return config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the config object of $http you have a field headers which is a map of strings or functions.

You can use it like that :

```
$http.get('/someUrl', { 
        headers: { Authorization : 'Basic ' + encoded}
});
```

Comment: Yes, but this way I have to add the 'X-WP-Nonce' headers in all the http requests. I am looking for a way to set the headers once in angular config. And change it when someone logs in.

Comment: Maybe $httpProvider.defaults.headers can help you so

Comment: Ok I'll try that in the future. I'll use your method for now. Many thanks!